# Merging tuples in a tuple with list and converting to dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples and a list.

```
 data = ((1, 'a', 'a1'), (2, 'b', 'b2'), (3, 'c', 'c2'))
 names = ['number', 'character', 'numchar']
```

How can I make it to dict looks like this?

```
 my_dict = {'number': [1, 2, 3], 'character': ['a','b','c'], 'numchar': ['a1','b2','c2']}
```

`len(data)` could be different from `len(names)`, but `len(data[0])` will always equal `len(names)`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(names,zip(*data)))
```